# Как правильно настроить статическую линковку системных библиотек?

Tags: c++

Линковщик выдаёт ошибку `LNK2001    unresolved external symbol __imp_StrChrA`. Насколько я понимаю, префикс `__imp__` появляется при динамической линковке библиотеки. Определила, что функция `StrChrA` находится в `shlwapi.dll`. Пытаясь статически прилинковать эту библиотеку по инструкции https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23882112/how-to-add-static-libraries-to-a-visual-studio-project попала в затруднительную ситуацию: в `Linker->General->Additional Library Directories` нужно указать директорию, в которой хранится соответствующий .lib-файл. Но у меня 12 таких директорий. Какую указать? Все (или опять же будут ошибки линковки из-за неоднозначности библиотеки)? Или соответствующую процессору, под который компилирую? Между `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.17134.0\um\arm64` и `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.16299.0\um\arm64` лучше выбрать первый путь?

Answer (score 1):

Системные библиотеки нельзя прилинковать статически. Имеющиеся .lib файлы для них - это импорты.

Comment: Если это системная библиотека, почему тогда линковщик выдавал ошибку?

Comment: @J.Huxley Наверное потому что библиотека не была прилинкована, нет? Почему вдруг вы решили линковать ее статически?

Comment: в начале файлов исходного кода, где использовался метод `StrChrA` я добавляла запись `#include <Shlwapi.h>`. Но ошибки линковки так и не пропали. После статической линковки в параметрах проекта исполняемый файл успешно сбилдился. Или есть ещё какие-то способы прилинковать библиотеку?

Comment: @J.Huxley `Shlwapi.h` - это заголовочный файл, содержащий объявления соотв. функций и типов, на линковку он никак не влияет. *"После статической линковки в параметрах проекта"* - ни о какой статической линковке тут речи быть не может, так как MS никогда не предоставляла такую возможность для системных библиотек. Если в настройках проекта прилинковать `Shlwapi.lib`, то будет производится линковка динамической библиотеки `Shlwapi.dll`, а не статическая.